# Renaming contents of text file using Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, eclipse

I have a text file with several lines in the following format:

```
gatename #outputs #inputs list_of_inputs_separated_by_spaces * gate_id

example: 
nand 3 2 10 11 * G0 (The two inputs to the nand gate are 10 and 11)
or 2 1 10 * G1 (The only input to the or gate is gate 10)
```

What I need to do is rename the contents such that I eliminate the #outputs column so that the end result is:

```
gatename #outputs list_of_inputs_separated_by_spaces * gate_id
nand 2 10 11 * G0
or 1 10 * G1
```

I tried using the find and replace function of Eclipse (the find parameter was a regex statement that didn't work), but it ended up messing up the gatename. I am considering using a Python script and iterating over each line of the text file. what I need help with is determining what the appropriate regex statement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use Eclipse's find and replace feature, using the following:

```
Find: ^([a-z]+) \d
Replace with: \1
```

This is essentially matching the gatename at the beginning of each line (`^([a-z]+)`) followed by the output (`\d`), and replacing it with just the matched gatename (`\1`).

Answer (score 4):

This is basically what the `cut` utility is for:

```
cut -d " " -f 1,3-
```

(update: I forgot the `-f` option, sorry.)

This takes a file, considers fields delimited by spaces, and outputs the first, third and following fields.

(If you're on Windows, you should have these [unix-style utilities](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) anyway, they can be incredibly useful.)

Using a regex, you could replace `(\w+) \d+ (.*)` with `$1 $2`.  Something like:

```
sed -r -e "s/([^ ]+) [0-9]+ (.*)/\1 \2/" file
```

or

```
perl -p -e "s/(\w+) \d+ (.*)/\1 $2/" file
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like...:

```
for theline in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
  print re.sub(r'(\w+\s*+)\d+\s+(.*)', r'\1\2', theline),
```

...should meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if it is this structured of a document, don't bother with a regex.

Just loop through the file, do a split on the " " character, then simply omit the second entry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what platform you're using Eclipse on, but if it's linux or you have cygwin, cut is very fast!

```
cut -d" " --complement -f2 $FILE
```

This will use space as the delimiter, and select the complement of the second field.

If you really want to use a regular expression, you can do something like this:

```
sed -r 's/^ *([^ ]+) +[^ ]+ +(.+)/\1 \2/' $FILE
```

You could easily use the same expression in python or perl, of course, but Mitchel's right - splitting is easy. (Unless the text is extremely long, and it'll waste time unnecessarily splitting other fields).

Comment: I'd suggest changing all the asterisks in that regex to plus signs — you need at least one space to delimit columns and at least one non-space to *be* a column. It'll make things considerably faster if it encounters lines which don't match.